# Netbeans C/C++ 7.2 -std=C++11 not recognized by gcc v4.6 or lower

Tags: gcc, netbeans, ide, ubuntu-12.04, system-administration

I left Eclipse to NetBeans for C/C++ development right after release v7 and it all seems a wise choice except that `-std=C++11` flag in the current latest release, namely 7.2, is not recognized by gcc 4.6 (`-std=C++0x`) or the previous. Since Ubuntu 12.04 ships with gcc 4.6 (which should be fair enough to use for my jobs in term of 11 features) and a fresh installation of gcc 4.7 might bring about complexity in maintenance of the system (well...I'm a person extremely simple, neat and clean), is there any work around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the "C++ standard" option from NetBeans does not work. My solution is to do it manually.
Add:

```
-std=c++0x
```

To the "Additional Options" in the Project > Settings > Build > C++ Compiler

Comment: Also checkout this link: http://mycomputeradventures.blogspot.com/2011/12/support-for-c0x-c11-in-netbeans.html