# error: ISO C forbids declaration of `test' with no type

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ by myself and I ran into this problem. I wrote several lines of simple code just wanted to test "auto", and it seems that it no longer works. I pasted my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto test=1;
    return 0;
}
```

Then the error in the title is reported. I use NetBeans IDE. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: But how should I configure my C++ compiler so that auto can be supported?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your compiler either doesn't support C++11 `auto`, or has it disabled (C++03 mode).

So the `auto` keyword, instead of meaning type inference, is a storage modifier.  And then the type is missing.

Comment: Thank you. But how should I configure my C++ compiler so that auto can be supported? I followed andre's link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921138/netbeans-c-c-7-2-std-c11-not-recognized-by-gcc-v4-6-or-lower/11942017#11942017), and I added -std=c++0x to Project Properties > Additional Options. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: @user2233131: If `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` is breaking things, try `-std=gnu++11` instead

Comment: The IDE gives me this error: cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11". The same happens for -std=c++11 and -std=c++0x.

Comment: @user2233131: These options are good for g++ 4.7.x.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry I haven't checked this website for a while. I actually have a problem checking the version of g++...whenever I run g++ -version, it gives me an error saying that g++.exe is not compatible with the version of windows I'm running. I'm running 64-bit OS. Could you please tell me how I can get around with this?

Answer (score 0):

To use the new C++11 meaning of `auto`, you have to have a compliant compiler, and tell it that the source file is using C++11 features.

With `gcc`, this is enabled using `-std=c++11`.